# Ambiguity in the word order either adjective vs adverb

Tags: grammar, adverbs, ambiguity, gerunds

There's one ambiguous structure I would like to clarify.

...by righteously maintaining his solitude...

Must I use righteous instead of righteously or is it the word order that must be changed?

Already grateful for every answer.

Comment: You could also say 'by maintaining his righteous solitude'.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that needs to be done to make the sentence more correct. The use of righteously is correct because it is an adverb, which modifies the verb "maintaining", whereas adjectives modify nouns.

Adverbs usually, but not always end in -ly (good/well is an exception, and to make matters worse, there is a separate adjective "well" which means something like healthy)